# Getting module of caller in Ruby

Tags: ruby, reflection

We have code to log data in our Ruby 1.8.6 web application.  You call it roughly as follows:

```
$log.info("Some text here")
```

Now, in the logged output, I would like to include the module where that line appeared.  I know that the `Kernel#caller` will give me an array where I can pull out the file and line number that the log line occurred, but I don't want that.  I want the module, not the file name.  The obvious solution is to modify the log line so that it reads like:

```
$log.info("Some text here", self.class.name)
```

and then parse the result.  That's not going to work, though, because I am trying to extract this information in the default case.  That is, I need the solution to work if the programmer forgot to specify the module, the second parameter to the log line.

Is there any way to do this?  If not, I will just have to make do with the `caller` array; most of our modules are in separate directories, so this would be an 80% solution.

More complete example, please excuse minor syntax errors:

in file log.rb:

```
module Log
  class Logger
    def info(msg, mod = '')
      puts "Module: #{mod}  Msg: #{msg}"
    end
  end # class Logger
end # module Log
$log = Log::Logger.new
```

in file foo.rb:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def do_something
      # Do not pass in self.class.name.
      # We want the output to look like:
      # Module: Foo  Msg: I did something!
      $log.info "I did something!"
    end
  end # class Bar
end #module Foo
```

Comment: I don't see how you can do it, unless to pass `self` or `binding` to the logger object.  You'd have to parse the file with the information from `caller`, which I'm sure you don't want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [call_stack](http://eigenclass.org/hiki/call_stack).

First install it with RubyGems:

```
gem install call_stack
```

Then change log.rb to:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'call_stack'

call_stack_on

module Log
  class Logger
    def info(msg, mod = '')
        mod = call_stack(2)[0][0] if mod == ''
        puts "Module: #{mod}  Msg: #{msg}"
    end
  end # class Logger
end # module Log
$log = Log::Logger.new
```

Works for me (Ruby 1.8.7).

```
$ ruby foo.rb
Module: Foo::Bar  Msg: I did something!
```

Comment: According to their site, we want to use ruby-debug instead, though the links appear broken.  It also notes that this involves a substantial slow-down.  Indeed, it may not even work.  Still, the best solution so far, so I'm +1'ing this answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Here's ruby-debug: http://rubyforge.org/projects/ruby-debug/ , and yeah, it'd be slow. Ruby's default support for callstack inspection is pathetic and there's been numerous suggestions to improve it, so all you get is Kernel#caller. Any solution would either involve tracing or working with the C api, so I represented what seems to be the simplest one. I suggest that if you really need this functionality you enforce a coding convention and always have programmers specify the module when calling (no default value). Inconvenient, but fast. Or you could turn off call_stack when not debugging.

Answer (score 3):

A mixin solves the OP's specific requirements (meanwhile, +1 to Asher for solving the generic "who called me" case!).

```
module Log
  module Logger
    def info(msg)
      puts "Module: #{self}  Msg: #{msg}"
    end
  end # class Logger
end # module Log

module Foo
  class Bar
    include Log::Logger
    def do_something
      # Do not pass in self.class.name.
      # We want the output to look like:
      # Module: Foo  Msg: I did something!
      info "I did something!"
    end
  end # class Bar
end # module Foo

foobar = Foo::Bar.new
foobar.do_something
```

Answer (score 2):

Came across this post while looking for an answer for my own purposes.

Didn't find one that was appropriate, so I dug through the Ruby source and put together an extension. I've bundled it as a gem- should install without any problem so long as you are using Ruby 1.9.1:

> sudo gem install sender

This *will not work* with Ruby 1.8, as 1.8 has a different model for tracking frames.

http://rubygems.org/gems/sender